# Finding the minimum difference of specific columns in each row rather than the entire dataframe in R (or finding closest value)

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a df that looks like this:

```
        expected_1      expected_2      actual_1       actual_2       actual_3
1               NA       1.0000000      0.2197744      0.9981707             NA
2               NA       1.0000000      0.3267090      0.9925908             NA
3               NA       1.0000000      0.2754576      0.9951685             NA
4               NA       1.0000000      0.1034605      0.4849989      0.9927820
5               NA       1.0000000      0.4100000      0.9952586             NA
6               NA       1.0000000      0.3727756      0.9708294             NA
7               NA       1.0000000      0.2672000      0.6850000      0.9800000
8               NA       1.0000000      0.2503922      0.9916763             NA
9               NA       0.5000000      0.4609574             NA             NA
10       0.3333333       0.6666667      0.3012779      0.6437114             NA
11       0.2500000       0.7500000      0.2980286      0.6383628      1.0000000
12       0.2000000       0.8000000      0.1831247      0.5060070      0.7086295
13       0.1428571       0.8571429      0.2914983      0.6599879             NA
14              NA       1.0000000      0.2934735      0.9923371             NA
```

For both expected_1 and expected_2, I would like to find the actual value that is closest to it. To first find what the minimum difference was for each row, I tried doing:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(
  min_dist_1 =  min(abs(actual_1 - expected_1), abs(actual_2 - expected_1), abs(actual_3 - expected_1), na.rm = T),
  min_dist_2 =  min(abs(actual_1 - expected_2), abs(actual_2 - expected_2), abs(actual_3 - expected_2), na.rm = T),
)
```

However, it just gives the minimum values for the entire df, rather than for each row.

```
          expected_1  expected_2     actual_1       actual_2           actual_3   min_dist_1              min_dist_2
1               NA       1.0000000      0.2197744      0.9981707             NA         0.003124393        3.414614e-05
2               NA       1.0000000      0.3267090      0.9925908             NA         0.003124393        3.414614e-05
3               NA       1.0000000      0.2754576      0.9951685             NA         0.003124393        3.414614e-05
4               NA       1.0000000      0.1034605      0.4849989      0.9927820         0.003124393        3.414614e-05
5               NA       1.0000000      0.4100000      0.9952586             NA         0.003124393        3.414614e-05
6               NA       1.0000000      0.3727756      0.9708294             NA         0.003124393        3.414614e-05
```

How can I find the minimum difference for each row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an base R option which should work for any number of expected and actual columns.

```
expected_cols <- grep('expected', names(df), value = TRUE)
actual_cols <- grep('actual', names(df), value = TRUE)
new_cols <- sub('expected', 'min_dist', expected_cols)

df[new_cols] <- lapply(expected_cols, function(x) 
                do.call(pmin, c(abs(df[[x]] - df[actual_cols]), na.rm = TRUE)))
df

#   expected_1 expected_2 actual_1 actual_2 actual_3 min_dist_1 min_dist_2
#1          NA      1.000    0.220    0.998       NA         NA    0.00183
#2          NA      1.000    0.327    0.993       NA         NA    0.00741
#3          NA      1.000    0.275    0.995       NA         NA    0.00483
#4          NA      1.000    0.103    0.485    0.993         NA    0.00722
#5          NA      1.000    0.410    0.995       NA         NA    0.00474
#6          NA      1.000    0.373    0.971       NA         NA    0.02917
#7          NA      1.000    0.267    0.685    0.980         NA    0.02000
#8          NA      1.000    0.250    0.992       NA         NA    0.00832
#9          NA      0.500    0.461       NA       NA         NA    0.03904
#10      0.333      0.667    0.301    0.644       NA     0.0321    0.02296
#11      0.250      0.750    0.298    0.638    1.000     0.0480    0.11164
#12      0.200      0.800    0.183    0.506    0.709     0.0169    0.09137
#13      0.143      0.857    0.291    0.660       NA     0.1486    0.19716
#14         NA      1.000    0.293    0.992       NA         NA    0.00766
```

Answer (score 2):

the main problem with your approach is that you are using the `min()` function, which is not vectorized. You should use `pmin()` or `pmap(min)`.

This will do what you want, and is a bit more concise:
First use `mutate` `across` the desired 'actual' columns to get the 'difference' columns. Then pipe these columns into `pmap(min)`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate('min_dist_1'=across(contains('actual'), ~abs(.x - expected_1)) %>% pmap(min, na.rm = TRUE),
              'min_dist_2'=across(contains('actual'), ~abs(.x - expected_2)) %>% pmap(min, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: where would the min value be after this?

Comment: please check if it is ok now

Comment: this worked for some rows, but how can I specify that it should omit NA values for the actual peaks? if any NA is present, the min comes up as NA

Comment: Just add the argument na.rm = true to the min function